# Setup rubocop with rubymine and docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubocop

I am running a rails app on docker, I now want to enable rubocop but when I am trying to I am getting the following.

```
Error:bundler: failed to load command: rubocop 
(/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/rubocop)
/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:41:in `block in for': 
Unable to find a spec satisfying nokogiri (>= 1.8.5) in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is 
corrupted? Found nokogiri (1.11.4-x86_64-linux) that did not match the current platform.
```

Inside container I am getting the following

```
ruby -v
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
which bundler
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundler
```

Outside the container on my machine

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
which bundler
/usr/bin/bundler
```

From what I understand rubocop looks for nokogiri on the gem installed by the container, so it can not find the correct version, can I install another nokogiri gem to be used from rubocop outside the container?

Answer (score 0):

RuboCop doesn't have any dependencies on nokogiri, so it feels like when bundler  is attempting to run `rubocop`, it is reporting a more general issue.

Is the `/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/` path in your initial error message a path within your container, or on your local machine? To me, it looks like the latter – and that means that your local rbenv copy of Ruby 3.0.1 may not have the full set of gems that your app, and RubyMine, are expecting of it based on your project's Gemfile.

In RubyMine's settings, you can set the project to use your container (Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Ruby SDK and Gems). If your Rails app is running in a container, you can create a remote SDK, and RubyMine will synchronise a local copy of the same gems (including RuboCop) for its own use.

I've had various problems with using RubyMine's synchronised gems in the past, and have sometimes instead used a local rbenv-based Ruby environment instead. However, if you go down this route it means you have to maintain that Ruby version's gemset yourself, and that means you lose a lot of the benefits of using a docker container for your development.